# Rotation animation jerks around on tap when using pause

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I have a image that rotates, and when you tap on it, it stops and gathers the rotation on it.  But for some reason, sometimes it jerks back (or around) from the position it was tapped.  Does anyone know how to fix this:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="AttackCircleAnimation">
<DoubleAnimation x:Name="combatCircleRotation"
  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
  Storyboard.TargetName="combatCircleSword" Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="360"   RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
</Storyboard>
</StackPanel.Resources>
</StackPanel>

<Image x:Name="combatCircleSword" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Tap="TapProcessAttack">
<Image.RenderTransform>
<CompositeTransform Rotation="0"/>
</Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

CODE:

```
private void TapProcessAttack(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
  AttackCircleAnimation.Pause();
  CompositeTransform t = combatCircleSword.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
  spinFinalValue = t.Rotation;
}
```